# Select query Prisma Client on Postgres view returning 0 rows when it shouldn't

Tags: postgresql, view, prisma

I am having a problem when trying to select rows from a Postgres view filtering by name.

The result from the query should be a company in company_portfolio named 'any company 2'. However, instead of returning the company, it returns nothing. By nothing I mean an empty array of companies instead of an array containing the company with the name 'any company 2'.

I have created a Postgres view that looks something like this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE view company_portfolio as
SELECT  company.id, 
        company.name, 
        ... 
    FROM "Company" company
        LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM 
            (SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM "Contract") a
             GROUP BY 1) as smpLists
    ON company.... = smpLists...
```

I have created a company with the name: 'any company 2'.

I am querying the table with my prisma client like this:

```
if (params.name) {
      filters = `${filters} AND "name" = '${params.name}'`;
    }


return this.prisma.$queryRaw(
      ` 
        SELECT * FROM "company_portfolio" 
        WHERE id IS NOT NULL ${filters}
        ORDER BY ${orderBy}
        LIMIT ${params.limit}
        OFFSET ${params.offset}
    `
    );
```

So the end query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "company_portfolio" 
        WHERE id IS NOT NULL  AND name = 'any company 2'
        ORDER BY name ASC
        LIMIT 1
        OFFSET 1
```

It is returning an empty array, so it is not properly selected the company with the name = 'any company 2'.

I have executed a similar query on the database directly and it returns the desired company.

Does anyone spot what could be wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. In particular here it seems you have a consistency problem. You "created a company with the name: 'any company 1'" then attempted to select the company name "'any company 2".  Well of course it did not find it, there is nothing to be found.  This could of course could just be a typo so perhaps you need to post actual tables and sample with sample data - as text, **no images**. Also include the complete view definition and the expected results on the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I was setting an offset = 1 and a limit = 1. This returns the second row from the select query result.

Since there was only 1 record meeting the criteria of the select query, there was not a second record, thus I was seeing an empty array.